# Hadoop cannot execute the command hdfs namenode -format

Tags: java, hadoop

[image: This is current status]

when I try to execute hdfs namenode -format, and commands like start.dfs do not work.

Comment: Please post your traceback/error in your question instead of screen-shot of it. also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Add `java` to your `PATH`

Comment: Whenever you get `No such file`... Actually go try and find it yourself... This isn't a Hadoop error, but Hadoop doesn't support Java 9, by the way

Answer (score 0):

hadoop needs JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME to be set. Check if you have set those, type env in terminal and grep for them. Based on your error its java path its not able to find